# Check if datatables is empty after table is fully loaded jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

After doing some research on this issue trying to find a solution (unfortunately to no avail) I decided that it might be best to post my problem. I currently have a Datatable containing asset information on a view and I'm trying to prevent a user from continuing change an option on a select field until an asset is added to the asset table.

Listed below is my assets datatable code in my .js file under the document.ready function

```
assets = $('#assets').dataTable({
    sAjaxSource: "http://" + window.location.hostname + "/request/get-request-assets/?id=" + $('#id').val(),
    fnDrawCallback: function (oSettings) {
        setIncompleteTD();
        enableRequestStatus();
    },
    scrollY: '185px',
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging: false,
    aaSorting: [[1, 'asc']],
    bPaginate: false,
    bFilter: false,
    bLengthChange: false,
    bAutoWidth: false,
    bInfo: false,
    aoColumns: [
        {sWidth: '35px', bSortable: false},
        {sWidth: '40px'},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {sWidth: '80px'}
    ],
    language: {
        sLoadingRecords: '',
        sEmptyTable: 'This request has no asset records.',
        sInfoEmpty: ''
    }
```

I've found **table.fnSettings().aoData.length===0** as a means to check if a table is empty. However, after stepping through the code (via Chrome debugger) it seems Datatables (at least in my case) calls the function before the table is fully generated...

I have this code below

```
assetPresent = (assets.fnSettings().aoData.length===0) ? false : true;
console.log(assetPresent);
```

in my document.ready function after $('#assets').dataTable() function (if this matters). **AssetPresent** will be used as a flag to toggle the status select box. Unfortunately before I can utilize that...

```
console.log(assetPresent);
```

Seems to always be set to false even if there are clearly records in the table, and...

```
assetPresent = (assets.fnSettings().aoData.length===0) ? false : true;
```

Tends to be ignored...

I'm curious to see if **table.fnSettings().aoData.length===0** might not be the best option. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried, table.data().length yet?

Comment: I have however, in that case assetPresent is always equal to true. Not entirely sure why, but my guess would have to be that even when the table is empty it's including  sEmptyTable: 'This request has no asset records.'  as a row in the table...

Comment: I would say its safe to assume if table.data().length returns undefined then there is no length you could also check if .data() is undefined too.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
var table = $('#assets').DataTable();

if ( ! table.data().any() ) {
   alert( 'Empty table' );
}
```